# How to open File Descriptor (3) from a Dart program

Tags: dart, filesystems

I'm creating a Dart program that communicate outside using File Descriptor 3.

Using let's say ruby I would do something like

```
out = IO.new(3)
```

What's the equivalent operation using Dart ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vyacheslav Egorov aka @mraleph clarified this :

you can't communicate with raw file descriptors using dart:io, this is not exposes through the APIs.